# how to make a new to collect the results of function ?

Tags: python, list

```
 t = [{"a" :11, "r_gr" :1, "gn":"F", "e" :18},
      {"a" :13, "r_gr" :3, "gn":"M", "e" :19},
      {"a" :1, "r_gr" :3, "gn":"M", "e" :29},
      {"a" :0, "r_gr" :2, "gn":"F", "e" :18},
      {"a" :0, "r_gr" :2, "gn":"M", "e" :18},
      {"a" :3, "r_gr" :1, "gn":"F", "e" :25}]
```

1. I want to make new list : s = [sum of "a"] like as [14,0,14] order by r_gr 
                        and r = ["r_gr"] like as [1,2,3]
                        and e = [first number of "e"]  like as [1,1,2,1,1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use `itertools` (builtin package) and some list comprehensions (i recommend this way):

```
import itertools
t.sort(key=lambda x: x['r_gr'])
a = [sum(int(item['a']) for item in group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(t, key=lambda x: x['r_gr'])]
r_gr = sorted(set([i['r_gr'] for i in t]),key=[i['r_gr'] for i in t].index)
e = [int(str(i)[0]) for i in [x['e'] for x in t]]
print(a)
print(r_gr)
print(e)
```

Output:

```
[14, 0, 14]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the pandas library, because it looks like these are easily solvable if you put them into a table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(t)
s = df.groupby("r_gr").sum().tolist()
r = df["r_gr"].sort_values().drop_duplicates().tolist()
e = df["e"].astype(str).str.slice(0, 1).astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Without pandas, how can I do that?